# Generator and actual variable values

Tags: python, generator

I need to write a function which returns an list of sum functions, adding an input number to some binded value. This is what i did:

```
def addition_range(start, end):
    if start >= end: return None

    #res = ( (lambda x: x + i) for i in range(start, end) ) #1
    res = [ (lambda x: x + i) for i in range(start, end) ] #2

    return res

for i in addition_range(0, 5): print( i(2) )
```

The output should be like: 2,3,4,5,6 but it's 6,6,6,6,6

The problem is in "i" variable, when i call the functions, they use actual value of i (4), not value used during generation of the list. The problem could be simply solved by using (#1) instead (#2), but i'm interested is there a solution for (#2)? I tried

```
res = [ (lambda x: x + copy.deepcopy(i)) for i in range(start, end) ]
```

but it doesn't help.

Thank you.

WinXP + Python 3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is by adding a dummy parameter:

```
def addition_range(start, end):
    res = [(lambda x, i=i: x + i) for i in range(start, end)]
    return res or None
```

The dummy parameter is evaluated at the time the lambda is defined, whereas your version evaluates `i` only when the lambda is called.

Side note: I added the `or None` part only to simulate the exact behaviour of your implementation.  It would probably be better to return an empty list instead of `None`:

```
def addition_range(start, end):
    return [(lambda x, i=i: x + i) for i in range(start, end)]
```